# MVC 4 adding sub-items to navigation menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design

I'm starting working with MVC4 (Responsive), HTML5 and CSS3.

I've created a new MVC4 Project, now i want to add sub items do the navigation menu, I want to keep the current structure to preserve responsiveness, I just want to add the sub items.

The HTML is like that:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Menu 1", "Index", "Home")
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub 1.3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS looks like:

```
/* menu */
nav {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

ul#menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

ul#menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

What changes do I have to do to make the drop down menu?

Comment: for drop down u need add some javascript. Just hide submenu <ul>'s and theh show/hide them with jasvascript on mouseenter/mouselive event on parent <li> element. But its just general direction. im not sure what u try to do. May be u need drop down on click event or something else

Answer (score 4):

You nest another `<ul>` inside of an `<li>`

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu4</a>
    <ul class='nested'>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SubMenu3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you'll want some styling on the nested ul to hide it until the users performs a mousehover over the parent `<li>`.

```
#nav ul{
    display : none;
}
#nav li:hover > ul{
    display : block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle for you to have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/8QtaL/6/

This is a pure html / css solution. No jQuery or javascript.